# OSX OpenGL depth stencil combination

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I am trying to create a frame buffer with a GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT TEXTURE on OSX 10.11.5 with an OpenGL 3.2 SDL context. It seems that the following line creates OpenGL error 1280:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT,  GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0);
```

This texture is generated as follows:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH32F_STENCIL8, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_FLOAT_32_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_REV, 0);
```

I know this is an OSX issue since this code used to work perfectly on my old Arch Linux computer. I did read the official [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_offscreen/opengl_offscreen.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH403-SW2) and there is no mention of a combined depth and stencil texture attachment. So is this functionality just not supported or am I doing it wrong? If this functionality is not supported, then what should I do as an alternative? Create 2 separate depth and stencil textures?

Answer (score 2):

Never sorry about this, but it turns out I was debugging wrong. OSX does support a stencil/depth hybrid even though Apple's documentation doesn't have much information on it. My error actually came from the next line, which was as follows:

```
glDrawBuffers(textureCount, allColorBuffers);
```

Which was wrong because texCount included the depth texture along with all my color buffers. So changing textureCount to textureCount-1 completely solved this.

Comment: Curious, are you using xcode to build your opengl software?